# WinUI 3: Office-Style File Menu

Tags: c#, winui-3

In Word (Office 365), when you click "File", a window opens that fully covers the Word window.

I tried to replicate this using Flyout, but with no success.

The problem is the placement and the width/height of the flyout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigation for this.

Let's say you have a **DocumentPage**, the `Page` where you can edit your document:

**DocumentPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WordNavigationExample.DocumentPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WordNavigationExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <MenuBar Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuBarItem
                Title="File"
                Tapped="MenuBarItem_File_Tapped" />
            <MenuBarItem Title="Home" />
            <MenuBarItem Title="Insert" />
        </MenuBar>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Padding="300,10,300,10">
            <Canvas Background="White" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**DocumentPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using System;

namespace WordNavigationExample;

public sealed partial class DocumentPage : Page
{
    public DocumentPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler? FilePageRequested;

    private void MenuBarItem_File_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FilePageRequested?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

and a **FilePage**, the `Page` that is navigated to, when the **File** item is clicked:

**FilePage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WordNavigationExample.FileMenuPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WordNavigationExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="File menu page" />
        <Button Content="Go back" Click="GoBackButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**FIlePage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace WordNavigationExample;

public sealed partial class FileMenuPage : Page
{
    public FileMenuPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler? GoBackRequested;

    private void GoBackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GoBackRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

and you can do the navigation in the **MainPage**:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WordNavigationExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WordNavigationExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System;

namespace WordNavigationExample;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        this.ContentFrame.Navigating += ContentFrame_Navigating;
        this.ContentFrame.Navigated += ContentFrame_Navigated;
    }

    private void ContentFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Frame frame)
        {
            if (frame.Content is DocumentPage documentPage)
            {
                documentPage.FilePageRequested -= DocumentPage_FilePageRequested;
            }
            else if (frame.Content is FileMenuPage fileMenuPage)
            {
                fileMenuPage.GoBackRequested -= FileMenuPage_GoBackRequested;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Content is DocumentPage documentPage)
        {
            documentPage.FilePageRequested += DocumentPage_FilePageRequested;
        }
        else if (e.Content is FileMenuPage fileMenuPage)
        {
            fileMenuPage.GoBackRequested += FileMenuPage_GoBackRequested;
        }
    }

    private void FileMenuPage_GoBackRequested(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(DocumentPage));
    }

    private void DocumentPage_FilePageRequested(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(FileMenuPage));
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(DocumentPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I was finally able to play around with your example. I am not happy with the paging mechanisms, but I was able to adapt your example so it works in my application. I still wish there was a solution using Flyout or similiar. Again, thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helped in some way.